# Remove String value from List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[{name=test19}, {name=test20}]
```

with the format

```
List<Map<String, Object>>
```

how can I remove "name=" from each element and the "{}" and add """" so the list looks like this:

```
["test19", "test20"]
```

It requires some kind of iteration, right? I have tried the example here [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)
but it doesn't work. Why it doesn't work is because it doesn't even go into the for loop (I have tried casting types etc)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `["test19", "test20"]` looks like a `List<String>`, so iterate over your map, and for each `Map.Entry`, use `list.add(entry.getValue())`.

Comment: Looks like you want to use `List<String>` instead of `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: I tried to edit the example which was provided in the thread I added, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need to fetch the `value`s from the pairs and store them in a list.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet) {
    list.add(entry.getValue());
}
String stringRepresentation = list.toString();
```

If you print `stringRepresentation` you will get the desired output

Comment: Well, maybe the OP could have tried by himself (even if you're probably right).

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand this, how does this remove those strings? Do you mean that I should convert it all to string and then remove them? Sorry for the misunderstandning

Comment: No, you don't remove anything. You have a map (a key-value data structure), from which you just *extract* the values and copy them into a separate list.